# How many invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}/(2p)\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, inverse

This question absolutely stumped me on my latest discrete maths exam. Looking to be pointed in the right direction so I can learn from it.

**Let $p\geq 3$ be a prime. In general, how many elements in $\mathbb{Z}/(2p)\mathbb{Z}$ are invertible?**

My only lead towards an answer is I know that $\forall [x] \in \mathbb{Z}/(p)\mathbb{Z} : \gcd(x, p) = 1$, or in other words, all $[x]$ are invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/(p)\mathbb{Z}$. How could I go from this knowledge to the number of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}/(2p)\mathbb{Z}$, or am I even on the right track?

Comment: multiples of $2$ and $p$ are not invertible in $\mathbb Z/(2p)\mathbb Z$

Comment: Do you know that$$[x]\in\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\text{ is invertible}\iff\gcd{(x,m)}=1$$

Comment: yes @PeterForeman, I use that result to conclude every element in $\mathbb{Z}/(p)\mathbb{Z}$ is invertible because every number is coprime with $p$.

Comment: What happens when you apply this result for $m=2p$?

Comment: I considered that yet quickly got stuck as well, I don't know how to make the jump from $\gcd(x,2p)=1$ to counting the number of invertible elements. I tried representing  $\gcd(x,2p)$ using Bézout coefficients as well.

Comment: Count the number of elements $x$ for which $\gcd(x,2p)=1$.  Which are those?  (Note:  $\gcd(x,2p)=1, 2, p, $ or $2p$.)  (Are we assuming $p\ne2$?)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner we're assuming $p \geq 3$. Sorry, I forgot about that! Edited the post. And those elements are ones which are coprime with $2p$ (almost by definition, so I don't know if that's what you're getting at).

Comment: How many elements are multiples of $2$? $p$? both? neither?

Comment: One piece of simple advice -- look at some specific small examples like $p=5, 7, 11$ etc. and find the pattern, if doing it with arbitrary $p$ is too confusing at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $p$ multiples of $2$ between $0$ and $2p-1$.

There are $2$ multiples of $p$ between $0$ and $2p-1$.

There is $1$ multiple of $2p$ between $0$ and $2p-1$.

Therefore, there are $2p-2-p+1=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{p-1}$ numbers relatively prime to $2p$ (invertible mod $2p$)

between $0$ and $2p-1$.

Using the Euler totient function, $\phi(2p)=\phi(2)\phi(p)=\phi(p)=p-1$.